# Grails 4.1.1 Data Service cannot be injected into Command Object: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I Have a simple design of Controller/Command/Data Service:

```
@Secured("ROLE_BACKEND")
class CommunityController {
    static namespace = "api"

    static allowedMethods = [index: "GET"]

    def index(GetCommunitiesRequest request) {
        respond request.execute(params).get()
    }
}
```

```
@CompileStatic
class GetCommunitiesRequest implements Validateable {
    @Autowired
    CommunityService communityService

    GetCommunitiesRequest() {
        println "Hello"
    }

    Boolean withPartners = false
    Integer max

    Try<List<Map>> execute(Map params) {
        def r = Try.of {
            params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
            communityService.list(params)
        }.map {communities->
            communities.collect {it.asMap(withPartners)}
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Service(Community)
interface CommunityService {

    abstract Community get(Serializable id)

    abstract List<Community> list(Map args)

    abstract Long count()

    abstract void delete(Serializable id)

    abstract Community save(Community community)

}
```

This is the UrlMappings file (just in case there is a link with namespacing the controller):

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        group "/api", {
            delete "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"delete", namespace:'api')
            get "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"index", namespace:'api')
            get "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"show", namespace:'api')
            post "/$controller(.$format)?"(action:"save", namespace:'api')
            put "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"update", namespace:'api')
            patch "/$controller/$id(.$format)?"(action:"patch", namespace:'api')

            "/"(controller: 'application', action: 'index', namespace:"api")
            "500"(view: '/error')
            "404"(view: '/notFound')
        }

        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller: 'application', action:'index')
        "500"(view: '/error')
        "404"(view: '/notFound')
    }
}
```

Most of this code is based on generated code by grails when using generate-all on my domain class. Obviously the added wrinkle is the Command (and the Try monad, but this should be irrelevant).

When I execute this endpoint I get the following exception:

```java
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:121)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:136)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:124)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.pr.request.GetCommunitiesRequest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'communityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.pr.data.service.CommunityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1425)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:392)
at grails.artefact.Controller$Trait$Helper.initializeCommandObject(Controller.groovy:456)
... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.pr.data.service.CommunityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
... 45 common frames omitted
```

Any idea on how to start investigating this issue? Obviously if you know the answer straight you're welcome :).

### What I tried

- I have tried step debugging the instantiation of the Command object (that's why I have added an empty constructor, tobe able to set a breakpoint), but I am struggling with the complexity of the ApplicationContext layer and I feel that I am not close to understand why this Service bean is not injected.
  The issue happens in grails.artefact.Controller#initializeCommandObject
- I installed the grails console plugin, and once the application starts up, I have tried accessing the communityService bean with `ctx.communityService` and got an propert bean in response: `com.example.pr.domain.$CommunityServiceImplementation@5deeeb12`
- In the same grails console, when I try to execute the following code:

```
def controller = ctx.getBean("com.example.pr.http.api.CommunityController")
  
controller.initializeCommandObject(com.examplep.pr.request.GetCommunitiesRequest, "request")
```

I get the same exception

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.pr.request.GetCommunitiesRequest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'communityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.pr.data.service.CommunityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Any help appreciated.

### UPDATE 1

Tried to remove the `@Autowired` annotation in the command object. It still fails, with a slightly different exception (`ConversionNotSupportedException`):

```java
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.example.pr.domain.$CommunityServiceImplementation' to required type 'com.example.pr.data.service.CommunityService' for property 'communityService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.example.pr.domain.$CommunityServiceImplementation' to required type 'com.example.pr.data.service.CommunityService' for property 'communityService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

    org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:595)
    org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:609)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1447)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:392)
    grails.artefact.Controller$Trait$Helper.initializeCommandObject(Controller.groovy:456)
    Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)
    org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleService.eval(ConsoleService.groovy:37)
    org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleController.execute(ConsoleController.groovy:53)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:82)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:136)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:124)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: the `communityService` doesn't seem to be a Grails Service, hence no auto-injection is possible. Where did you put it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look! The `CommunityService` is indeed a grails service, it is under services/. The fact that I can lookup the service (second bullet point in my tries) proves it, and moreover proves that it can be looked up in the grails application context. The thing that does not seem to work is `initializeCommandObject`.

Comment: Thank you @Injecteer your comment, though it was not the real issue, made me investigate a little deeper what I had in services/ and this lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had mistakenly created a copy of my `CommunityService` Data Service in a different package.
Grails got confused when trying to instantiate the Command object when it tried to autowire it and somehow did not report that there were 2 candidates (?).

I had two identical copies of the Service:

- `com.example.pr.domain.CommunityService` (generated by generate-all)
- `com.example.pr.service.data.CommunityService` (attempt to repackage to a more logical package structure and not place the Service in the `domain` package)